# Why is an IoC/DI container called a 'container'?

Tags: dependency-injection, naming-conventions, inversion-of-control, conventions

I'm just trying to understand where the label 'container' came from. Anyone know?

Seems like many things could be called 'containers'.

Comment: @TheDeeno - It would be nice to give the courtesy of a response if you are going ask a question. Even if it is to say that everyone is clueless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it serves as container for objects. It is the framework that manages their lifecycle. It is responsible to instantiate, resolve references and destroy them.

Answer (score 3):

In order to differentiate it from a **factory**, which doesn't keep instances alive.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it "contains" object definitions (and manages object creation and destruction).

What's in a name.

Answer (score 0):

The word collection is intended to hide the implementation of a collection or container of things.  You can't call it a list, array or stack because those are specific kinds of implementations.  Collection would also work but Container is the word that caught on.

Answer (score -2):

Because it sounds friendlier than framework.

Comment: Are you kidding? -1 for this unrelated answer.